# Microsoft Edge positions divs incorrectly when the website is first loaded, or refreshed by re-entering URL

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge

as mentioned in the title, when I load [my website](https://8000plus.si/kcgsi) the second div goes under the first div, which it shouldn't and if I open the website in any other browser (Chrome, Firefox) it works as it should.

To make the animation I call a JS function on load.

I really don't know what's the deal, even when I put CSS through [this website](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) it changes nothing...

HTML:

```js
function test() {
  $('.animacija').each(function(index, element) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      element.classList.remove('anim8');
    }, index);
  });
}
```

```css
.vrsta2 {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 91vh;
  border: 0px;
}

.animacija {
  transition-duration: 2s;
  width: 50%;
}

.animacija.anim8:nth-child(even) {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.animacija.anim8:nth-child(odd) {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

#kolo {
  width: 50%;
  height: 91vh;
  background-image: url(uploads/images/kolo/kolo_trgovina_2.jpg);
  background-size: cover, 0px, 0px, 0px;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  float: left;
}

#moto {
  width: 50%;
  height: 91vh;
  background-image: url(uploads/images/moto/moto_trgovina.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
}

.trgovina1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 91vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3vw;
  padding: 300px 20% 0px 20%;
  color: #EED484;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}

.trgovina2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 91vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3vw;
  padding: 300px 20% 0px 20%;
  color: #EED484;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}

div.trgovina1:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

div.trgovina2:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onLoad="JavaScript:test();">
  <div class="vrsta2">
    <div class="animacija anim8" id="kolo">
      <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="opencart/index.php?route=product/category&path=158">
        <div class="trgovina1">Enter<br><i class="fi-shopping-cart" style="color: #E7C355; font-size:4rem;"></i></div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="animacija anim8" id="moto">
      <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://8000plus.si/RAZVOJ/kcgsi/opencart/index.php?route=product/category&path=60">
       <div class="trgovina2 ">Enter<i class="fi-shopping-cart " style="color: #E7C355; font-size:4rem; "></i></div>
      </a>
     </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi! I converted your code block to a runnable snippet, and it revealed that there is a syntax error in `<a style="text-decoration: none;" href=url ">`, could you please edit it and put what you had intended? Probably not the cause of your problem, but you never know...

Comment: added the url, the synatx error was because there was a missing " before url.